# Heroku Scheduler Rails Whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduled-tasks, rake-task

I am aware of the Heroku Scheduler addon. However I would like a task to run every (for example) 36 hours to simulate human activity.  How can I do this with or without Heroku Scheduler?

This is my first attempt at rake task and I have them all configured successfully. I just need my task to be executed less than or more than 24 hours apart, not the same time everyday.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use scheduler and have the task run every hour, just have it execute every 36 hours somehow.  You can do something like hours since a date in the past mod (%) 36 = 0.  Have it run on the half hour so you're sure to get it in the middle of the hour every hour.